# Does the ToLookup method return the Lookup class?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

The answer to this question seems simple. After all, if you check the documentation of `ToLookup` method from the `IEnumerable` interface, then it says that it returns `Lookup` class, and the documentation of `Lookup` class, then it says the only way to create it is through the `ToLookup` method. However, if you look at the type of the `ToLookup` method, then you'll quickly notice that it doesn't return the `Lookup` class. Instead, it returns an instance of the `ILookup` interface.

So my question is: does it really return the `Lookup` class or not? If it does actually return that class, then what's the reason for returning it as an interface even though the documentation says it returns the class? Would it be safe to write `(Lookup<TFoo, TBar>)foo.ToLookup(bar)` or could someone write an implementation of `ToLookup` which actually returns a different class other than `Lookup` which also can't be cast to it?

Comment: It returns an instance of the `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` class, which implements the `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` interface.

Comment: You are actually asking three different questions, with three different answer. Which question exactly do you want answered in particular?

Comment: Should I split it into 3 different questions on this site then? And primarily the first one, but the others are heavily related too.

Comment: It is not untrue.  There are two implementations of ILookup, they are both called Lookup.  The non-obvious one is System.Linq.Parallel.Lookup, it is internal.  Brr, anything with "parallel" in its name seems to have been written by a bunch of cowboys.

Comment: @TheRedFox The concrete instance returning by `ToLookup()` depends on the implementation. Check the source code like https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L973. Why is it important to know if the class implementing the `ILookup` interface is in fact the `System.Linq.Lookup` class?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not always perfect, as also here. Actually it returns an instance of `ILookup<TKey,TElement>`, the only class available currently implementing that interface is `Lookup<TKey,TElement>`. So whenever they decide to return something else they will break the documentation and probably also existing code which assumes that there is always an `Lookup<TKey,TElement>`.

So if you want to be on the safe side declare the type with `var` or `ILookup<TKey,TElement>`.

In general it's better to return an interface instead of a concrete implementation, so you are free to change the implementation later without breaking any code.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Parallel/Utils/Lookup.cs,1cf57abff3a9d17d

Comment: "better to return an instance" should be "better to return an *interface*", right?